# Regex to match the last number on different rows

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match the last number from a different row, looking like:

`Total fara TVA                                     TVA                                          Total 171,11 RON                                         32,51 RON                                    203,62 RON`

What I want: `203,62`

What I'm trying regexr.com/64to5 : `Total(?:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)){1}`

What I get: `171,11`

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might use a capture group:

```
\bTotal\b.*(?<![\d,])(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\b
```

- `\bTotal\b` Match Total between word boundaries to prevent a partial match
- `.*` Match any char except a newline
- `(?<![\d,])` Negative lookahead, assert not a digit or , to the left
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:,\d+)?` Match 1+ digit with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y2MCtj/1)

If you don't want to cross matching Total again before the number:

```
 \bTotal\b(?:(?!\bTotal\b).)*(?<![\d,])(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XclEfS/1)

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
\bTotal.*(?<=\s)(\d+,\d+)\s+
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/FK97mE/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
\bTotal.*  ##Using word boundary along with string Total followed by .* greedy match here.
(?<=\s)    ##using positive look behind to make sure spaces are present before next mentioned regex.
(\d+,\d+)  ##Creating 1st capturing group to match 1 or more occurrences of digits followed by comma and followed by 1 or more digits.
\s+        ##matching 1 or more occurrences of spaces here.
```

***OR*** as per fourth brid's nice suggestion: without positive lookbehind try following:

```
\bTotal.*\s(\d+,\d+)\s+
```

Comment: @shAkur, could you please do let me know if my answer has worked for you?